# Updating an entry through mongoose without ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose schema defined as

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    user_id: String,
    event_organizer: [String],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

Now, I have a function where I wish to add this User's Id to an event. Ofcourse, this event is already present in the DB.

```
function addUserToEvent(user_id, event_id) {

}
```

How do I add an `event_id` to the user's `event_organizer` array as defined in the schema?

It is possible that the array is already populated and I need to append the id, not reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you append an element to an array in an existing document:

```
Document.update(
     {_id:existing_document_id}, 
     {$push: {array: element}}, 
     {upsert: true}
) /*upsert true if you want mongoose to create the document in case it does not exist*/
```

For your specific case:

```
function addUserToEvent(user_id, event_id) {
    User.update(
                {_id:user_id}, 
                {$push: {event_organizer: event_id}}, 
                {upsert: true}
    )
}
```